# Rails using fire-base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firebase

I have problem during using fire-base with rails to making a real time form in rails with fire-base how it will be done .. please help me i am new in fire-base. 
**How to make a real time sharing form in Rails using fire-base.**

sorry for bad English ;)

Answer (score 1):

It would be good if you can use ids as keys for each of your form element like input ,select etc and can place value for the element to make each key-value pairs.

This would be effective in a case when you have a persistent record for that form i.e for make new records this approach is not good.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [firebase-rails](https://github.com/oscardelben/firebase-ruby) gem, it's description reads as follows: Ruby

> wrapper for the Firebase REST API.
>
> Changes are sent to all subscribed clients automatically, so you can
>   update your clients in realtime from the backend.

It's very easy to use, although the documentation is somewhat lack luster for but it's just enough for a simple app (if you don't know what you're doing).